# How to be able to use a content once in a content field?

Tags: nodes, entities

I created a field in to a content. Let's call the content type **National Anthem** and the field **Country**. **Country** is a content type too.

What I'd like to do is to forbid the use of a country which has been chosen already.
*
For example, let's say that we have the country *Germany*, *France* and *United-Kingdom*. If I create a new **National Anthem** and for the field **Country**, I choose *United-Kingdom*. I now create a new **National Anthem** and I can only choose between *France* and *Germany*.

Thank you.

Comment: Nice question. You should be able to use the views based entity reference widget for this. Let me see if I can turn this into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using an entity reference (default reference in Drupal 8, and provided by the [Entity Reference module](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) for Drupal 7). You can do this with an entity reference view:

[image: Entity reference view]

Create a new view that lists *content* of type *Country*. Then take the following steps:

1. Make sure to add a new *Entity Reference* Display.
2. Enable the *title field* as *Search field* in the formatter settings. (Behind drop down menu.)
3. Add a relation of type *Content using field_country*.
4. Filter content that has no value for *ID* using the relationship.
5. (optional), if you reference country from more content types than *National Anthem*, filter also for the *Content type* to be of *National Anthem*; again using the relationship.

This view will select all countries, which are used on nodes with no ID. (Thus are not referenced.)

Finally, make sure you enable the view in the content type's field settings:

[image: Field settings]

Comment: Your answer is really complete but I do'nt understand why we are using a view in this case and how doing this will oblige to choose only once a country in the field *Country* of a **National Anthem** content.

Comment: This is not a view for display. You do not need to create a page or block. Instead, this view is used to genereate a dynamic option list for an entity reference field. Make sure you do step 1. Then you can select this view if you edit the field settings on the content type.

Comment: May I ask you to explain me how doing this can limit the use of a content to once in this field?

Comment: Have you tried it? As explained in the comment above, the view will be used  to generate a dynamic list of available options.  Since the view only lists countries without anthem, so will the reference field.

Comment: I didn't want to try before understanding how it works. I believe it's a better way to learn. After your explanations, I understand what you are doing. Although, I have a last question:

"(optional), if you reference country from more content types than National Anthem, filter also for the Content type to be of National Anthem; again using the relationship."
I am not sure to understand it well. Is it to be able to use this view for any content? I would prefer to not create a view per content type which uses **Country**.

Comment: No, you misunderstood. The view will leave out all countries that are referenced from any node. This means that if another content type uses the country, it won't be available for national anthem anymore. In that case you will have to filter (step 5) by the national anthem content type, to make sure you only select country nodes that are not used on any national anthem nodes.

Comment: And if I want the same for the flags, I need to create an other view and use a filter (with flag this time)?

Comment: I suppose that would be a new separate question (You can link to this one to provide context). But why would you create a content type for flags? Aren't those just image fields on the counties?

Comment: Again, that's an example. But if you want an explanation, I guess it's possible to have an explanation of the colors, etc, the history of flag and so on.
Then, I don't want to ask an other question because it's what I wanted from the start...